# Extract all tables inserted/selected inside a procedure of a package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a package which has many procedures defined inside it. I need to get all the tables that are being referenced which are either inserted into or selected inside this procedure. Note some procedures might have procedures inside them from other packages.
Also any possibility i can differentiate which is being inserted and from table data is just being selected.
Not sure how to build the SQL query for the same.
Take example
Package name: APP
procedure name: app_get_data

Comment: You are probably going to have to parse the SQL text for that. You could try to look at the `USER_DEPENDENCIES` (or `ALL_DEPENDENCIES`) table but there can be dependencies on a table for its column data types without even using an `INSERT` or `SELECT` ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=641396bdc02d1ae929f5b3917580ca90)) so you cannot rely on that to tell you what you want to know.

Comment: Alright could you help me with  the query i can use to just get the references of tables used for my package whether inserted/selected or referenced for data type

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the table dependencies for a package (and recursively from other dependent packages) then you can use the `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` table and a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   ALL_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE  REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE'
START WITH
       OWNER = 'YOUR_USER'
AND    TYPE  = 'PACKAGE'
AND    NAME  = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       (   PRIOR REFERENCED_OWNER = OWNER
       AND PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME  = NAME
       AND PRIOR REFERENCED_TYPE  = TYPE
       )
OR     (   PRIOR OWNER = OWNER
       AND PRIOR NAME  = NAME
       AND PRIOR TYPE  = 'PACKAGE'
       AND TYPE        = 'PACKAGE BODY'
       );
```

If you want to take it further and break it down into specific procedures in a package and into whether a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `MERGE` or, for example, if the column was just referenced for its data type then you are probably going to have to parse the SQL text for that package.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3f96d8e8698587139680d6542011b89a)*

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by parse the SQL text for this package. And also how to achieve that

Comment: Also do I need SQL parsing for a procedure too ?

Comment: Or if i could use this SQL block for procedure what parameters should i pass

Comment: @THeParadigmShifter Parse the SQL text for the package means: in the simple case, something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251914/1509264) then look a splitting the package into procedures and searching for table names; or in the complex case, build an abstract syntax tree for the package and its contained statements then extract the table names ([maybe look at his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752034/how-do-i-access-the-ast-abstract-syntax-tree-for-a-pl-sql-stored-procedure)). This is something that would take a lot of effort and is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: If you want to search procedures that are outside of packages then change the `START WITH` clause to `OWNER = 'YOUR_USER' AND TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' AND NAME = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE'`. If you are trying to search individual procedures inside of packages then the entire package is aggregated together within the `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` table and it is impossible to get more granularity than the dependencies across the entire package.

Comment: Can you give me the snippet that is be used for a particular procedure inside a particular package i tried with and command but it's not showing up

Comment: @THeParadigmShifter As I said, changing the `START WITH` clause to use `TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'` is for globally defined procedures that are **outside** of a package. If you want to parse a package and find dependencies **inside** a specific package procedure then you will need to use the SQL text and that is far too complicated a solution to knock up in 10-20 minutes as a StackOverflow answer (as a reliable solution would be to generate an abstract syntax tree and then parse that); if you want that as a solution then you are going to need to code it yourself or wait for someone else to answer.

Comment: Oh understood i was just thinking if that's possible to do some AND clauses and check that out. Well thanks a lot you helped a lot today. Will try to figure out a SQL parser solution and hopefully someone else gives an answer that would be great too.

Comment: @THeParadigmShifter If it is a one-off activity then you are probably going to be quicker to do it by hand and can start by using the output from the query above (possibly removing the `DISTINCT` clause and the `WHERE` filter to get all the intermediate steps) and go through every dependency by hand and create a flow chart (or similar). The only value to writing a parser is if you need to do this repeatedly (and then you may want to question why you need to do it rather than having decent documentation of the packages to start with).